# Is there a way to connect Social Studio with Email Studio and/or Sales Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud

I'm looking for a way to find subscribers engaging with us through social and create data extensions for them for later targeting. I know I can create a case through a macro, but is there any other connection to Sales Cloud or Email Studio functionality from within Social Studio?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no connection of this type. This is not a functional limitation but a legal one.

Most countries laws and also the social networks terms of use require the users consent to be added to a marketing data base. Your scenario effectively precludes this requirement.

Under those circumstances your process will also violate the Salesforce terms your company (or your customer) signed at the risk of a contract penalty and service shutdown. This is supposed to prevent harm to the Saleaforce sender reputation caused by too many unsolicited e-mail (Spam).

Summarized: Don't do this at all :)

Comment: Thank you, Stephan. How about for the subscribers who are using social media? Is their any connection between the clouds and Social Studio in that regard, aside from the case/service macro?

Comment: The only standard one I'm aware of is with Advertising Studio. This allows to target Twitter users in Advertising Studio based on Twitter search profiles created in Social Studio.