# How does Social Studio connect Facebook users to their CRM contacts?

Tags: marketing-cloud, facebook, social-studio

We have requirements to score Contacts based on their Social interactions.
(e.g. +1 pt for like, +5 pts for comment)

Is this possible in Social Studio?

In demos, we see the cool feature to create a case, etc. based on a Facebook comment.

Do these cases map to an existing CRM Contact? If so, how?

Technically, I don't see how we'd have a CRM_ID for a Facebook user - so my guess is that it's one-way? (i.e. new SF Contact created on first case-creation from Social Studio).

Alternatively, is there an API that can be triggered on Social Interactions?

**PS**

To clarify, this is for higher-ed, the target audience are alumni so there is consent to eventually contacting them.

Found this in my research: [Is there a way to connect Social Studio with Email Studio and/or Sales Cloud?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/267398/is-there-a-way-to-connect-social-studio-with-email-studio-and-or-sales-cloud)

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is no.

As I wrote in the answer you already linked this is a legal and contractual issue. You attempt to scrape user interaction details from Facebook to combine it with personal data you have to score people towards a marketing target. Facebook doesn't allow this sort of thing for good reasons, ethical and legal.

For those reasons there is no API to do this sort of thing.